# Separating particles

Tags: particles

How can I separate an object’s particles from each other, by loose parts, after I applied on it a quick explode? The usual way of P while in edit mode does not work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Quick explode uses modifiers to generate the result, the original object is still the same. In object mode pressing Alt-C will apply all the modifiers, you can then go into edit mode and separate by loose parts.

Comment: Sambler, thank you for your advice. I am away from my computer but will let you know the results within a few days, as soon as I get back.

Comment: Sambler, thank you so much. Your solution works well and I easily managed to separate my particles.